# Poner cabecera en las clases y el autor

Tags: java, eclipse

Quiero poner la cabecera en toda clase que cree pero de forma automatica.
La idea es que quede asi

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Todos los derechos reservados.
 */

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * @author VADIROCA 
 *
 */
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CaberceraTallerPermisos extends PermisoBase {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2L;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez abierto eclipse, debes ir al siguiente menú

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Eclipse -> Settings -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí vas a ver un menú con un panel que tiene de título **Configure generated code and comments**. Seleccionas donde dice **Code -> New Java File** y das click al botón **Edit**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez ahí, armas el template como más te guste. Como puedes ver, se pueden utlizar distintas variables y modificar también la parte autogenerada de otras cosas como `clases`, `métodos`, `atributos`, etc. Según el caso planteado, con agregar la **cabecera** que mostraste arriba de todo, debería ser suficiente para que cada vez que crees un nuevo archivo **java** pudiendo ser una `clase`, `interface`, `enum`, etc se le agregue automáticamente. Algo así debería quedarte

```java
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Todos los derechos reservados.
 */
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```